# Universal property of the tensor product, balanced product vs bilinearity

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

For modules over commutative rings, we can define the tensor product via bilinear maps. For modules over non-commutative rings the more general notion of a balanced map is used.
The definition of a balanced map is looser than that of a bilinear map, even in the case of modules over commutative rings.

> $f$ is balanced if $f(r\cdot m,n)=f(m,r\cdot n)$, however $f$ is bilinear if $f(r\cdot m,n)=f(m,r\cdot n)=r\cdot f(m,n)$.

This definition really is looser as we can see with an example from a similar question.
The example is: Let $S$ be the free $R[x]$ module with basis $\{1,y,y^2,...\}$ were the module structure is defined by $x\cdot y=-yx$. Then the multiplication map from $S\times S\rightarrow S$ is not bilinear but it is balanced.

Do the definitions of tensor product via bilinear and balanced maps coincide? Suppose $P$ is the tensor product of $M$ and $N$. If we have a bilinear map from $M\times N$ to $P$ this is also a balanced map, and hence by the uniqueness from the universal property the two definitions agree. Where I am skeptical however is, if we have a balanced map from $M\times N$ to $P$ how do we know that there will exist a bilnear map. It seems that by using the definition that requires bilinear maps we are missing out on some tensor products.

Is the resolution of this that we can construct the tensor product using free modules of the product and a suitable quotient. The map to this construction will be bilinear by definition. Then we get the uniqueness from the universal property.

Since the tensor product is unique up to unique isomorphism it seems that we cannot have a balanced $A$-module morphism from $M\times N$ to $P$ that is not bilinear, but this seems to contradict the example above?

- Do the definitions via balanced map and bilinear map coincide for modules over commutative rings?
- Can there exist a balanced $A$-module morphism $M\times N \rightarrow P$ that is not bilinear in the case that $A$ is commutative?

---

Here is the question from which the example was taken from ([Tensor products- balanced maps versus bilinear](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1059782/tensor-products-balanced-maps-versus-bilinear)).

Comment: I'm confused by your example in a few ways: (1) If you tell me $S$ is the free $R[x]$-module with basis $\{1,y,y^2,\dots\}$, then I already know its module structure: you just told me it's free with the given basis. Then $x\cdot y$ cannot be equal to any element but $x\cdot y$. (2) In any case, I wasn't sure what $x\cdot y = -yx$ meant, because I wasn't sure how to interpret $yx$ as an element of $S$. (3) I wasn't sure what you meant by "the multiplication map $S\times S\rightarrow S$"; from context I'm guessing that on the basis it acts as $y^i\cdot y^j = y^{i+j}$, but, e.g., what's (cont'd)

Comment: $(y\cdot x) \cdot (y\cdot x)$? Perhaps at this stage is where you meant to involve the idea that $x$ and $y$ anticommute? (So it's not the $R[x]$-module structure of $S$ you're trying to describe, but rather the multiplication map?)

Comment: As an aside, I have never heard of the notion of a balanced map in your sense; to me, if $R$ is a noncommutative ring, $M$ is a right $R$-module, and $N$ is a left $R$-module, a map $\varphi: M\times N\rightarrow T$ to an abelian group $T$ is already called "bilinear" if $\varphi(m,-)$ and $\varphi(-,n)$ are group homomorphisms $N\rightarrow T$ and $M\rightarrow T$ respectively, and $\varphi(mr,n)=\varphi(m,rn)$ for all $m\in M, r\in R, n\in N$. Nonetheless, I have a guess that your question might be answered by this previous question? https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2091423/13120